# Bashrc not able to chain commands anymore using && or ;

Tags: linux, bash, shell, bashrc

You guys are my last resort.

I've got a bashrc file with all kinds of commands in it. A lot of them are variations to this

```
alias test='
    test1 && test2
'
alias test1='
    echo "i hope" && \
    echo "this works"
'
alias test2='
    echo "because" && \
    echo "it annoys the hell out of me"
'
```

This used to work up until a few days ago. Since then I've been getting the following errors

```
$ test
i hope
this works
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `&&'
```

No matter if I use `&&` or `;`. The commands test1 and test2 work as expected seperatly, but I can't chain them anymore.
My shell is in bash and I've had several colleagues look at it, but no one has any idea what's wrong.

```
$ echo $SHELL
/bin/bash
```

Am I missing something? It's just weird that all of this used to work but all of a sudden it doesn't anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alias replaces text with text. There is no logic, there's only text replacement. In your case consider using shell functions instead. Please see [*In Bash, when to alias, when to script, and when to write a function?*](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/30925/108618)

After Bash expands your `test`, it expands `test1` and `test2`. No problem here, such multi-level expansion is allowed. But because the replacement is purely textual, all characters matter. Characters that seem harmless in one definition may change the logic of the final outcome, because it's the final outcome what is interpreted eventually.

Your `test` expands to:

```
    test1 && test2
```

and then it expands to:

```
    
    echo "i hope" && \
    echo "this works"
 && …
```

where `…` denotes what `test2` expanded to (irrelevant to the issue). Only then the outcome is interpreted.

The newline after `"it works"` is the final character from the expansion of `test1`. It is unescaped, it terminates the preceding command. `&&` in the next line is unexpected.

It would be different if the troublesome newline wasn't there:

```
alias test1='
    echo "i hope" && \
    echo "this works"'
```

or if it was escaped:

```
alias test1='
    echo "i hope" && \
    echo "this works"\
'
```

I believe I explained the problem and "fixed" it. Nevertheless I think **the Right Thing is not to use aliases this way**. Aliases using aliases to build some logic should be replaced by functions calling functions. [Aliases are not for building logic](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/30950/108618).

If `test1` and `test2` were properly working shell functions (I mean each working on its own), then the expression `test1 && test2` would work as expected, regardless of newlines in the definition of `test1`. This would work because the logic of the expression would be determined before `test1` and (optionally) `test2` are executed. In case of aliases `test1` and `test2` are expanded before the shell tries to determine the logic and (as we could see) they can affect the logic.

It's not only about newlines. Execute the following example:

```sh
alias foo='echo 1; echo 2'
false && foo
```

If you don't know `foo` is an alias (or if you do, but you don't know how aliasing works) then you will expect `foo` in `false && foo` to be omitted as a whole. No, `echo 2` will be executed. This is because the final command is `false && echo 1; echo 2` and its logic is different than what you expected.

An "equivalent" shell function behaves better. The following snippet won't execute `foo` at all, exactly as you expect from `false && foo`:

```sh
unalias foo
foo() { echo 1; echo 2; }
false && foo
```

**For me, understanding that an alias dumbly replaces *text with text* was a turning point. All my troubles with aliases stemmed from not realizing this basic fact.**

---

Additionally note `test` is a [standard command](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html). You shouldn't create an alias or a function named `test`, unless your goal is to deliberately replace the standard `test`.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I changed everything to functions as you said. Now it works as expected. I was already thinking about doing this. The aliasses were originally very small but they grew into more complex pieces of code.